# foreach loop from $_GET is adding strange values

Tags: php, facebook

I have the following piece of code that is supposed to create a coma separated string from a URL returned when somebody installs a Facebook Tab:

```
$tabs_added = $_GET['tabs_added'];
$tabs_added_array = array();
foreach($tabs_added as $key => $value){
    $tabs_added_array[] = $key;
}
$the_tabs = implode(',', $tabs_added_array);
```

The page is called and returned by Facebook like this:

```
tabs.php?tabs_added[1202358366491085]=1&tabs_added[144695175064017]=1
&tabs_added[676066073448810]=1#_=_
```

For some strange reason, the string it generates however is:

```
1202358366491085,144695175064017,676066073448810,0,1,2
```

As you can see, the beginning is correct, but then it adds `0,1,2` for no reason. Why is that and how can I avoid this?

Comment: i tried your code and there is no `0,1,2` ...

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($_GET['tabs_added']);`?

Comment: The var_dump also shows `int(1202358366491085) int(144695175064017) int(676066073448810) int(0) int(1) int(2)` I think the problem is the strange =1#_=_ that Facebook adds at the end.

Comment: I think you're not showing us everything though.

Comment: Unfortunately that's all the code there is :( The rest is just HTML. No other `$_GET['tabs_added']`

Comment: When you have another tabs_added in the url, will it show: `int(0) int(1) int(2) int(3)`?

Comment: Yep, indeed it does! Wow, that's strange.

Comment: I know what the 0,1,2,3 are but I dont know what's wrong with the code you have. Wait up.

Answer (score 0):

Your array looks like this:

```
[0]=>[1202358366491085]
[1]=>[144695175064017]
[2]=>[676066073448810]
```

Try it out with: `var_dump($tabs_added_array);` after the foreach.

And the string gets both. The code you show is not producing the indexes of the array though.

I've tested this myself and this is the URL I have:

```
test.php?
tabs_added[1202358366491085]=1&tabs_added[144695175064017]=1
&tabs_added[676066073448810]=1#_=_
```

And my code:

```
$tabs_added = $_GET['tabs_added'];
$tabs_added_array = array();
foreach($tabs_added as $key => $value){
    $tabs_added_array[] = $key;
}
$the_tabs = implode(',', $tabs_added_array);
var_dump($tabs_added_array);
```

There must be something else in the code you're not showing us whether you know it or not.

Comment: Actually, you're somewhat right. The var_dump I did was on the $key inside the foreach loop. Doh! Doing it outside, I get the same array as you.

Comment: @user1227914 So when you use: `echo $the_tabs;` outside of the for loop, does it show the right tabs?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. That's the problem. When I do a `var_dump($tabs_added);` it shows the array like yours above, however.

Comment: @user1227914 Yeah but how about `echo $the_tabs;` outside of the for loop?

Comment: `var_dump($tabs_added_array);` AFTER the foreach and BEFORE the implode gives me this: `array(6) { [0]=> int(1202358366491085) [1]=> int(144695175064017) [2]=> int(676066073448810) [3]=> int(0) [4]=> int(1) [5]=> int(2) } `

Comment: @user1227914 read my comments again :P. Im not telling you to `var_dump($tabs_added_array);`

Comment: Yeah, I did an `echo $the_tabs;` right after the implode and it gives me the 0,1,2 stuff still.

Comment: @user1227914 It cant be if you're using the code I just produced though... Like literally copy/pasted my code.

Comment: Note you code does `var_dump($tabs_added_array);` though. And I tried both. Before the implode it gives me the array with the 0,1,2 and after the implode `$the_tabs` gives me still the 0,1,2. I know it can't be, but it does. And it's sad that I just pulled out my last hair, too =P

Comment: @user1227914 Please try to find the differences between my code and your REAL code(I assume this isn't literally your code). I cant help any further cause the problem is something we cant see. We're not experiencing this problem with the information you produced.

Comment: I'm trying and I REALLY appreciate your effort but I literally copied and pasted it into my code and replace everything except the HTML. Is there perhaps any other way of getting the data into a coma separated string?

Comment: @user1227914 Not that I can think of no and there's probably something wrong with the data you're getting and we cant see the data your getting except for the url you're giving us and that's fine. It already starts at the `$tabs_added = $_GET['tabs_added'];` since when you var_dump that, you already get the 0,1,2. Right after you declared $tabs_added, (so before the foreach) and `var_dump($tabs_added);` before the foreach, do you still get the 0,1,2?

Comment: I tried doing this

`foreach($_GET['tabs_added'] AS $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;
}`

And it shows fine. But then I added the `$tabs_added_array[]` instead of the echo and it goes wrong again. I think it's got to do something with the array part.

Comment: Nevermind, it still addres the 0,1 at the end of the string. Even with the foreach and without array.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this to fix my problem:

```
foreach($tabs_added_array as $key => $val) {
    if(strlen($val) <= 3)
        unset($tabs_added_array[$key]);
}
```

Yes, it's a dirty fix. But I didn't know how else to do it. It didn't fix the problem, but it's a solution.

Comment: Yep that's real dirty xD. I've thought about giving you something like this as well as an alternate answer but I just couldn't do it. Good luck though.